# decompress an archive in android

Tags: android

Does anybody knows how could one programmatically decompress an archive in android ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZipInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

Just search google for how to decompress files in java, there are tons of tutorials.

Comment: Could there be a problem if a file is compressed with gzip and I try to decompress it like a zip archive ?

Comment: @klaus-vlad: GZIPInputStream: This class is a part of java.util.zip package.